# multiple loops in a view mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

If I have the following code would it be possible to have two  view data on a single view?
How would I go about doing this
Many thanks in advance
Hesh

```
public ActionResult Index(long id = 0)
        {
            var contentPage = (from c in db.Tble_content
                               where c.id == id
                               select c);
            var contentlist = (from c in db.Tble_content
                                       where c.EN_TopPageID == id
                                       select c);
            return View();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little more code would help. But assuming your `Tble_content` has a structure like this:

```
public class Tble_content {
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Content{get;set;}
}
```

you can have a viewmodel like this:

```
public class ContentViewModel {
    public string ContentPage {get;set;}
    public string ContentList {get;set;}
}
```

and you pass it to a view like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(long id = 0)
{
    var contentPage = (from c in db.Tble_content
                        where c.id == id
                        select c);
    var contentlist = (from c in db.Tble_content
                                where c.EN_TopPageID == id
                                select c);

    return View(new ContentViewModel {
       ContentPage = contentPage,
       ContentList = contentlist
    });
}
```

Comment: Von
Sorry for the little code, but this is was what I needed to get it to work
many thanks for your help
Hesh